# Dark mode multiple id and class selection doesnt work

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid, getelementsbyclassname, darkmode, queryselector

I'm trying to make darkmode, but I'm having trouble with batch class and id selection and saving to localstorage. The function does not save to localstorage and takes the .header in elementbodydark selection. In Elementcomponentdark, it does not select any of them. How can I fix this function and batch select class and id at the same time? Any help? Thank you so much

```
    function darkmode() {
  var elementbodylightClass = document.querySelector("a");
  var elementbodylightId = document.querySelector("#gundem-section");

  var elementbodydarkClass = document.querySelector(".header");
  var elementbodydarkId = document.querySelector(
    "#slide-sec, #kesfet, #currency-weather"
  );

  var elementcomponentdarkClass = document.querySelector(
    ".top-header, .main-news-navbar"
  );
  var elementcomponentdarkId = document.querySelector("a");

  var elementcomponentwhiteClass = document.querySelector("a");
  var elementcomponentwhiteId = document.querySelector("a");

  localStorage.setItem("dark-mode-active", "true");

  localStorage.getItem("dark-mode-active") === "true"
    ? elementbodydarkClass.classList?.add("dark-mode-dark-body")
    : "";
  localStorage.getItem("dark-mode-active") === "true"
    ? elementbodydarkId.classList?.add("dark-mode-dark-body")
    : "";

  localStorage.getItem("dark-mode-active") === "true"
    ? elementbodylightClass.classList?.add("dark-mode-light-body")
    : "";
  localStorage.getItem("dark-mode-active") === "true"
    ? elementbodylightId.classList?.add("dark-mode-light-body")
    : "";

  localStorage.getItem("dark-mode-active") === "true"
    ? elementcomponentdarkClass.classList?.add("dark-mode-dark-components")
    : "";
  localStorage.getItem("dark-mode-active") === "true"
    ? elementcomponentdarkId.classList?.add("dark-mode-dark-components")
    : "";

  localStorage.getItem("dark-mode-active") === "true"
    ? elementcomponentwhiteClass.classList?.add("dark-mode-white-components")
    : "";
  localStorage.getItem("dark-mode-active") === "true"
    ? elementcomponentwhiteId.classList?.add("dark-mode-white-components")
    : "";
}

function darkmodeoff() {
  var elementbodylightClass = document.querySelector("a");
  var elementbodylightId = document.querySelector("#gundem-section");

  var elementbodydarkClass = document.querySelector(".header");
  var elementbodydarkId = document.querySelector(
    "#slide-sec, #kesfet, #currency-weather"
  );

  var elementcomponentdarkClass = document.querySelector(
    ".top-header, .main-news-navbar"
  );
  var elementcomponentdarkId = document.querySelector("a");

  var elementcomponentwhiteClass = document.querySelector("a");
  var elementcomponentwhiteId = document.querySelector("a");

  localStorage.setItem("dark-mode-active", "false");

  localStorage.getItem("dark-mode-active") === "false"
    ? elementbodydarkClass.classList?.remove("dark-mode-dark-body")
    : "";
  localStorage.getItem("dark-mode-active") === "false"
    ? elementbodydarkId.classList?.remove("dark-mode-dark-body")
    : "";

  localStorage.getItem("dark-mode-active") === "false"
    ? elementbodylightClass.classList?.remove("dark-mode-light-body")
    : "";
  localStorage.getItem("dark-mode-active") === "false"
    ? elementbodylightId.classList?.remove("dark-mode-light-body")
    : "";

  localStorage.getItem("dark-mode-active") === "false"
    ? elementcomponentdarkClass.classList?.remove("dark-mode-dark-components")
    : "";
  localStorage.getItem("dark-mode-active") === "false"
    ? elementcomponentdarkId.classList?.remove("dark-mode-dark-components")
    : "";

  localStorage.getItem("dark-mode-active") === "false"
    ? elementcomponentwhiteClass.classList?.remove("dark-mode-white-components")
    : "";
  localStorage.getItem("dark-mode-active") === "false"
    ? elementcomponentwhiteId.classList?.remove("dark-mode-white-components")
    : "";
}
console.log("asd");

function onload() {
  var elementbodylightClass = document.querySelector("a");
  var elementbodylightId = document.querySelector("#gundem-section");

  var elementbodydarkClass = document.querySelector(".header");
  var elementbodydarkId = document.querySelector(
    "#slide-sec, #kesfet, #currency-weather"
  );

  var elementcomponentdarkClass = document.querySelector(
    ".top-header, .main-news-navbar"
  );
  var elementcomponentdarkId = document.querySelector("a");

  var elementcomponentwhiteClass = document.querySelector("a");
  var elementcomponentwhiteId = document.querySelector("a");

  localStorage.getItem("dark-mode-active") === "true"
    ? elementbodydarkClass.classList?.toggle("dark-mode-dark-body")
    : elementbodydarkClass.classList?.remove("dark-mode-dark-body");

  localStorage.getItem("dark-mode-active") === "true"
    ? elementbodydarkId.classList?.toggle("dark-mode-dark-body")
    : elementbodydarkId.classList?.remove("dark-mode-dark-body");

  localStorage.getItem("dark-mode-active") === "true"
    ? elementbodylightClass.classList?.toggle("dark-mode-light-body")
    : elementbodylightClass.classList?.remove("dark-mode-light-body");

  localStorage.getItem("dark-mode-active") === "true"
    ? elementbodylightId.classList?.toggle("dark-mode-light-body")
    : elementbodylightId.classList?.remove("dark-mode-light-body");

  localStorage.getItem("dark-mode-active") === "true"
    ? elementcomponentwhiteClass.classList?.toggle("dark-mode-white-components")
    : elementcomponentwhiteClass.classList?.remove(
        "dark-mode-white-components"
      );

  localStorage.getItem("dark-mode-active") === "true"
    ? elementcomponentwhiteId.classList?.toggle("dark-mode-white-components")
    : elementcomponentwhiteId.classList?.remove("dark-mode-white-components");

  localStorage.getItem("dark-mode-active") === "true"
    ? elementcomponentdarkClass.classList?.toggle("dark-mode-dark-components")
    : elementcomponentdarkClass.classList?.remove("dark-mode-dark-components");

  localStorage.getItem("dark-mode-active") === "true"
    ? elementcomponentdarkId.classList?.toggle("dark-mode-dark-components")
    : elementcomponentdarkId.classList?.remove("dark-mode-dark-components");
}
```

Comment: You should include your html for reference, but the first thing I notice is that you are using `document.querySelector()` which selects the first item that matches. Thus `elementbodylightClass`, `elementcomponentdarkId`, `elementcomponentwhiteClass`, and `elementcomponentwhiteId` (and probably more) all refer to the same element.  Perhaps try `document.querySelectorAll(...)` and loop over the collections returned.

Comment: Ty for answer. I changed than showed up this errors:  main.js:271 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'add')
    at darkmode (main.js:271:38)
    at HTMLDivElement.onclick (front.html:63:59)

main.js:368 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toggle')

Comment: It's hard to say without your html and where it's erroring. What are you calling `toggle()` on? What is that item when you are calling toggle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created fully functional dark mode. New codes here;

choose components ;

```
 const elementbodylightId = Array.from(
    document.querySelectorAll(
      "#gundem-section, #etkinlik-section, #straight-mainpage-img"
    )
  );
```

save localstore;

```
  localStorage.getItem("dark-mode-active") === "true";
  for (var i = 0; i < elementbodylightId.length; i++) {
    elementbodylightId[i].classList.add("dark-mode-light-body");
  }
```

for onload ;

```
 for (var i = 0; i < elementbodydarkId.length; i++) {
    if (localStorage.getItem("dark-mode-active") === "true") {
      elementbodydarkId[i].classList.toggle("dark-mode-dark-body");
    } else {
      elementbodydarkId[i].classList.remove("dark-mode-dark-body");
    }
  }
```